# How to read data after converting from DataTable to an IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>?

Tags: c#, linq

I converted a System.Data.DataTable to type IEnumerable[Dictionary[[string, object]] and called it myDataTable. Now, how do I read each row and its value using linq?

```
    dtReports = new myDataTable(e.Result);                 

    foreach (myDataRow row in dtReports.Rows)
    {
        string group = row.GetType().GetProperty("Group").GetValue(row, null);
    }
```

This isnt working for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Group" is the name of the column...

Using LINQ:

```
 var listOfGroups = from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    select row["Group"];
```

Or, using the LINQ extension methods and a lambda:

```
 var listOfGroups = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["Group"]);
```

Comment: I am just trying to read row values for a certain column.. I think i got the answer.. you just have to say pair.GetType().GetProperty("Group").GetValue(pair, null)

Comment: You're using reflection there which is expensive and I can guarantee you unnecessarily (and slow).

Comment: You are right, using reflection makes it slow. Your solution using Linq works for me.. Thanks